# login y creación de sesiones con PHP y mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy intentando crear sesiones de usuarios. Tengo una tabla de **usuarios** y una de **tipo_usuarios** en esta tengo 4 tipos distintos, **administrador**, **usuario**, **vl** y **fl**. Pero no consigo que se creen las sesiones, todos van a la misma página.

**Función login**

```
function login($usuario, $password)
{
    global $mysqli;

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, id_tipo, password FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ? || correo = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $usuario, $usuario);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $rows = $stmt->num_rows;

    if($rows > 0) {

        if(isActivo($usuario)){

            $stmt->bind_result($id, $id_tipo, $passwd);
            $stmt->fetch();

            $validaPassw = password_verify($password, $passwd);

            if($validaPassw){

                lastSession($id);
                $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $id;
                $_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] = $id_tipo;

                header("location: usuario.php");
                } else {

                $errors = "La contrase&ntilde;a es incorrecta";
            }
            } else {
            $errors = 'El usuario no esta activo';
        }
        } else {
        $errors = "El nombre de usuario o contrase&ntilde;a no existen";
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

Una vez el usuario hace el `login` debe de ir a su página, pero van todos a la misma.

**Usuario - VL**

```
<?php
session_start();
    require 'funcs/funcs.php';
    require 'funcs/conexion.php';



    if(!isset ($_SESSION["id_usuario"])) {
        header("location: index.php");
    }


    $idusuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
    $tipo_usuario = $_SESSION['id_tipo'];

    $sql = "SELECT id, nombre, id_tipo FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$idusuario' and id_tipo = '3'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

?>
```

Me podéis por favor ayudar?

Comment: Buenas, por encima lo que veo es que si el usuario existe en la base de datos creas la variable de session id_usuario y tipo_usuario y lo mandas a la pagina usuario.php y si en usuario.php haces un echo  $_SESSION['id_usuario']Y UN echo $_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] te saldra dependiendo del usuario con el que loguees

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. No tendría que ponerlo aquí? if($validaPassw){

                lastSession($id);
                $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $id;
                $_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] = $id_tipo;

                header("location: usuario.php");
                } else {                                                                    según el tipo de usuario 1, 2 , 3 4 llevarle a una página o a otra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que debes usar una redirección a la pagina dependiendo del tipo de usuario que se loguea. Para ello necesitas tener un pagina diferente para cada tipo de usuario.

```
if($id_tipo == "administrador"){
  header("location: indexAdministrador.php");
} elseif($id_tipo == "usuario") {
  header("location: indexUsuario.php");
} elseif($id_tipo == "vl") {
  header("location: indexVl.php");
} else { //Se asume que la última opción es usuario tipo fl
  header("location: indexFl.php");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Así lo he resuelto.

Comment: Si la respuesta resolvió tu inquietud, recuerda marcarla como útil. [Aquí encuentras información al respecto.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)